# Do my cloud-shaped letters work in terms of readability and recognisability?

Tags: logo, typography, critique

I have the following design (in two variations):

[image]

It is not final yet. Ultimately I need to show that monsoon brings rain. I will add rain elements around clouds later.

My main doubt is about the clouds used for *o* and *oo,* respectively.
My goal is to represent clouds without losing much readability. Personally, I really feel clouds are representing the letters well enough.

Is this good in terms of readability and representing clouds? Is there something obvious which I can improve?

Comment: I edited the question to focus on one aspect that was also answered. Please do not fundamentally change a critique question after an answer was given.

Comment: Note that the on-topicness of this question is debated in the comments on [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/126606/19174).

Comment: Your letters are not readable, One must stop to guess. Even less they resemble something rainy. Forget that idea. As well than having clouds in text you can have text in a cloud. That cloud can be rainful. Here's one not so serious example : https://www.dropbox.com/s/3rl98au9uyydukz/2Hunt351.jpg?dl=0

Comment: @user287001 this was first step. I've to add rain elements below it. It will look rainy. Secondly, you clearly said *Forget that idea*. Kindly look at this https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-vector-creative-typography-th-of-july-world-hepatitis-day-prevent-hepatitis-poster-template-brown-453971023.jpg How easy is this to understand?

Comment: *Forget that idea*. I have a strong feeling if a good creative mind can still fix it if letters are not visible. I don't think at all the idea of playing with clouds and O is bad.

Comment: @Vikas The linked WORLD has splinters, their only intended recognization result is O and R, you aim to have double interpretation. It's possible without reading difficulties if an established letter shape and the 2nd meaning are equal in a little unsharp image. A banana can be C, a football can be O, a matchstick can be I etc.. I cannot imagine how a round O could be at the same time be much wider than it's high. M,  OO or MON could. But your passion made me unsure. There can be another possiblity than a trivial geometric shape correlation. I will return if I see it. Thanks for the reveille.

Comment: @user287001 *their only intended recognization* No. They are representing the letters and a human liver. It also has double interpretation. You just can't say it's NOT POSSIBLE. IT IS, YES IT IS! Even though I can't do it in a better way. Don't take it as an argument :) I've a very strong belief about it.

Comment: Had it been so simple, I wouldn't ask it here.

Comment: I guess I get thrown out if say somewhere "this is liver shaped" Doctors and autopsy specialists maybe are different when they talk with each other.

Comment: @user287001 *Doctors and autopsy specialists maybe are different when they talk with each other* What do you mean by this?

Comment: They probably have developed in their studies and work an ability to connect text "human liver" to a certain common geometric shape which is for them as established as for example U-shaped for me.

Comment: @user287001 but that image is not only to be shared with doctors, but with whole world.

Comment: I guess organ shape aware specialists only have some difficulties to read it.

Comment: *I guess organ shape aware specialists only have some difficulties to read it.* Now you may be wondering I'm asking question for your every response. But something is not right here. I can't understand what you mean. @user287001

Comment: @Mari-Lou A would you please decipher it?

Comment: They see at first a liver and then some letters, pieces of R and wonder how in the hell they belong together? The recognition happens after a while like it happened in 5 seconds after seeing your monsoon, but the reading doesn't happen at first because the interesting bit is not readable.

Comment: But hey probably have no difficulties to see what XXockMusic means where XX is the liver shape.

Comment: @user287001 my only intention was to say that if my design (after adding rain drops as well) is a fail, this liver one is also fail. There's not a big difference. People understand Clouds and rains more easily than liver.

Comment: But I guess you're trying to say that liver one was better than mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inconsistencies kill this for me.

One cloud is "overly" puffy with many "poofs". While the other.... has none. This factor is far too distracting overall. Visual consistency should be considered, in my opinion. Solid or hollow makes no difference. I can't get past this discrepancy.

- It's easy to accept the first image as a cloud.... but then you see the second which is *entirely* different, not merely "doubled" for the `oo`.
- Okay, so the second image is a cloud... then the first one is a meatball???

Frankly, I just thought of a *flipped* Adobe's Creative Cloud logo shape where the second cloud is concerned - while a "targeted" visual audience, it's not *that* small.

[image: cc-flipped]

In addition, the stroke weight of the `s` *feels* too thick. I realize it's not, but due to the tight curves it gives off that impression.

---

**After edit**

All the above still stands in my opinion.. and the rain adds very little other than further distraction.

Comment: Hi, the stroke weight wasn't final yet. Okay, so I've decided I should go with solid shapes so far. If I choose the version you showed (i.e., less width of cloud), will it be representing OO better than I've shared?

Comment: Can you please tell me reason why this question is opinion based? Close requests are always ready whenever I post something, which requires efforts to answer. @Scott

Comment: Questions may be marked as opinion-based because they are too subjective. If one answer could be *"I looks good."* and another *"It doesn't look good."* and **both** are equally valid answers -- then it's all *opinion* and there's no way to choose a "correct" answer. If you review the [critique guidelines](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/672/guidelines-for-critique-questions), you'll see some examples of questions which are subjective in nature but allow for solid, quantifiable, answers.

Comment: Many of your questions are, or at least start, similar to *"do you like blue or do you like red?"* -- how on Earth is there a "correct' answer to that type of question? `:)`.

Comment: it's not like that. I believe one of them is better but I can't decide. If you share a poll about it (let's neglect both are bad), one of them will get significantly more vote from designers for sure.

Comment: @Vikas Not sure why tagging doesn't seem to be working for you. Hard to tell on *this* question since it's my answer I get notified either way. And if you are seeking a "poll" that is *clear* indicator that you are seeking merely *opinions*. "Polls" are very off-topic on stack sites. And *that* may be specifically *why* you get close vote for opinion-based questions.

Comment: I've edit the question BTW. Hope you won't mind. I feel it's better now.

Comment: I do not feel the edit is better.. it merely asks for *opinions* regarding the rain as well  now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96175/discussion-between-vikas-and-scott).

Comment: In the future, please debate the on-topicness of a question on the question itself so potential close voters can see it. For whatever it’s worth, I think that this answer quite well demonstrates why the question is *not* opinion-based: You do not just answer with *I don’t like it,* but you give an elaborate answer illustrating the problems of the design in an objective way. This is as objective as critique questions can possibly get. (CC @Vikas)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft it's impossible to debate here with downvoters. Nobody accepts my points. I HAVE TO change the question the way they want. No point of debate.

Comment: @Scott did you specify that CC cloud icon only because it would fit better with the given left cloud icon I used?

Comment: No. I mentioned that the left cloud you used reminded me heavily of the Adobe CC logo. I wasn't suggesting *using* that shape. I was suggesting that shape may be *mad* because it's already used by Adobe.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [what Scott noted about your clouds not matching](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/126606/19174), I think you are facing the following dilemma: A cloud shape that can be recognised as such has to have a certain complexity, while still being all round and geometric. By contrast, typefaces that are mostly round and geometric are almost inevitably not complex.
So either your clouds stand out as too complex or your typeface does not match your clouds. To avoid this dilemma as far as possible, your clouds need to be as simple as possible.

Also, regarding readability, the main thing that makes letters distinct is some vertical element. Your *oo* cloud is lacking this.

Here is a quick attempt of mine to address this:

[image: solution sketch]

I used three circles instead of the minimal two for the cloud since the resulting shape is closer to a rotational symmetry and thus an *o.* Also, this allows for a clear separation in the *oo* cloud. Note how the top part of all letters has exactly the shapes as the regular word *monsoon:*

[image]

Comment: But no body will accept them as clouds.

Comment: @Vikas: I wouldn’t be so sure about this, in particular if you add rain. It also depends on how important it is that the clouds are identified as such. That being said, I don’t claim that my sketch solves all your problems, it just shows a direction for you to explore.

Answer (score 1):

I think choosing a design that provides a perfect depiction can be a bit of a drag. I've taking a close look at this design and I believe the solid cloud provides a more accurate representation of "soon" in "monsoon". However, you might wanna consider adding the rain drops beneath the "oo". The overall design is pretty simple and minimal which is a good thing in my opinion.

I am still new to Logo Design so perhaps a second opinion will go a long way in reassuring you.

Answer (score 1):

For me the inconsistency in cloud-forms is quite jarring - but far worse is the conceptual inconsistency - in the case of the O, one multiply-complex-curved agglomarative cloud represents a single, simple-formed rounded letter, whereas in the double O following, a single, far formally simpler cloud is representing two of that same letter>

That's ***far*** *before* the specifics of the chosen æsthetics - this is top-level-graphic-concept *whoops* territory - and for me, though I like the second cloud form well enough (I do work in a tech environment and so have had to reconcile myself to that particular hackneyed "cloud" iconography) and don't prefer the fussiness and busyness of that first cloud (which just doesn't say "proxy for an 'o' to me) I never even really **get** to those considerations - I'm blown off-course out of the gate by the conceptual mis-match.

Hope that helps.